Is there a way to get rid of the underline visual in Dotnet Maui Entry on android
I am trying to figure out how to style an Entry control in dotnet Maui so the black line shown in the image do not show up on android as there is no property to set.
I assume I need to invoke a handler to get rid of it, but the problem is i cant figure out which one to use if any. Do any know how to fix this problem without having To rely on Something like DevExpress?

I Do fear the problem with the entry control is much larger in the sense that each entry type on windows, android and IOS lack overlap of styling options forcing some default values that is not easy to change. For instance an entry on WinUI is a TextBox. By default it displays a border around it and have padding option to determine the distance between the input text and the border. However the Dotnet Maui Entry have no Border or padding options to set. I assume that it is because that at least one of the equivalent control on Android or IOS It is not possible to apply padding or a border to

It does help with the problem in the sense that the line is gone but disables the ability to set a background color at all.
